# domain doesnt go to default.aspx when set

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

Hi there currently I have a default.aspx file that I am trying to have show up when my domain is searched.

So far i've checked stackoverflow and have been given this general solution.

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="default.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
```

This has gotten me nowhere. I also tried the default settings that get given aswell which show default.aspx as a Default Document in the Default Documents section [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Grw.png)

All of these solutions kept showing the 404 not found page.

Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od2XO.png) of my bindings
404 URL: https://ro-aviation.com

Comment: We need to see your <sites> tag in applicationHost.config and the actual URL that gives you 404. Note that without such, this is impossible to be discussed further.

Comment: @LexLi I have just added a screenshot of my bindings and the URL if its of any help to you.

Comment: Next, what's the IP address you see from `ping ro-aviation.com`? Is it the one associated with this server? Also enable FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing and see if you can capture more about such 404.

Comment: @LexLi  I can't seem to find FRT and the IP Address given by the site is different to the servers ip but isn't that to be expected?

Comment: If your network administrators are doing their jobs well, then that's unexpected. https://halfblood.pro/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef Like I wrote years ago, your very first stage of testing should be on that server, so that `ro-aviation.com` should resolve to `127.0.0.1`. Only when everything is fine, you can move to stage 2 and `ro-aviation.com` resolves to the server's internal IP address in the network. Lastly in the last stage you let it resolve to the desired public IP address. Don't jump too far, or you fall hard.

Comment: @LexLi how would that process have helped me with this default document issue out of curiosity? Since wouldn't I just be in the same situation just without the site on the public ip address.

Comment: I don't think you received 404 because of the default document setting. Period. With so many essential settings (like domain/IP resolution) unchecked, even the source of the 404 page is unclear. It can come from another machine/device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add a redirect inside in my Global.asax file as I have done below.

File: Global.asax

```cs
    public class Global : HttpApplication {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            // Code that runs on application startup
           AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
           RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
        void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if (Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath == "~/") {
                HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("default.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have a single file (Default.aspx) or you have a Asp.Net Web Forms project?

You will not be able to host the single Default.aspx file directly in the IIS. If you do so, you will receive errors upon visiting the page in the browser.

[image]

First, you need to publish your Asp.Net Web Forms project from the Visual Studio.

[image]

Then you need to attach that published site folder with the IIS site in the IIS.

[image]

Then you need to create bindings for your site.

[image]

If you do above 2 steps properly then when you visit your site, the Default.aspx page will get disaplayed.

As it is default page, you do not need to configure anything special.

Comment: Hi there, yeah its a webforms project. I've published the project from VS and added it in the same way you have. I have a screenshot of my bindings also just added to the post now. The only difference I can see is that you have a wwwroot folder, I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: I would like to confirm, if you visit the site from the same machine where you hosted it, are you getting 404 or do you see your site?

Comment: I get the 404 from that machine aswell. It seems to show up like this in VS aswell when i test it.

Comment: While running the project from VS If VS also shows the 404 then we need to check the project. Have you made any changes in the project for default page?

Comment: I have tried adding it into the web config file in vs and ive also left the default documents section blank in it.

Comment: I would suggest reverting the changes you made for testing purposes, then run the project and see which page it opens by Default? For reference, you could check the content of `web.config` file by creating a new project.

Comment: I eventually found a solution just now searching another issue someone had. I'll post it into here.